# How to show the data from the api to the nested field in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'


export const addToCart = (uid, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/`)

    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product: data.uid,
            name: data.name,
            images: {[
                url: data.url,
            ]} 
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            qty
        }
    })

    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
```

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'


export const addToCart = (uid, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/`)

    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product: data.uid,
            name: data.name,
            **images: {[
                url: data.url, this part is where the challenge
            ]}** 
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            qty
        }
    })

    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}
```

This is what I came up with but it seems I have made a mistake on the nested image value but everything works just fine...can someone help me with that bit there

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch({
type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
payload: {
    product: data.uid,
    name: data.name,
    images:{
     url: data.url
    },
    price: data.price,
    countInStock: data.countInStock,
    qty
}
})
```

Here you can use Images as object like images.url
or,

```
images:[
 {
    url:data.uri
 }
]
```

you can access from images[indexvalue].url
Depends on your requirement

Comment: it did'nt work is there another way of aproaching this